# Jmeter regular extractor default values when there are two or more templates

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

How to pass default values to Jmeter regular extractor when there are two or more templates.

In the screenshot below, I like to set the values for Code_Id_article_g1=""g1_default" and Code_Id_article_g2=""g2_default". Note: Since I am doing random extract to I don't want to split the regular exp ( I need the pair) Thanks

[image]

Comment: If it matters, what is the text of the regular expression in text form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) you can create [only one variable](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/extractor/RegexExtractor.java#L114) using Regular Expression Extractor and it will be `Code_id_article` having the value from the "Default value"

You can consider switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which allows creating 2 variables with 2 different default values or [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) where you will have the complete freedom regadring how many variables to create, how they will be called and what will be their default values.

Moreover [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) and using regular expressions for parsing it is not the best idea.